# insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext: returning NSNumber bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm relatively well versed in CoreData and have been using it for several years with little or no difficulty. For the life of me, I can't figure out why

```
insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:
```

is all of a sudden returning some sort of strange instance of NSNumber. GDB says the returned object is of the correct custom subclass of NSManagedObject, but when I go to print a description of the NSManagedObject itself, I get the following error:

```
*** -[NSCFNumber objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3f26f50
```

What's even stranger, is that I'm able to set some relationships and attributes using setValue:forKey: and all is good. But when I try to set one specific relationship, I get this error:

```
*** -[NSCFNumber entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3f26f50
```

I've tried everything from clean all targets, to restarting both mac and iPhone, even editing the model so that the relationship in question is to-one instead of to-many. No matter what I do, the same problem appears. Has anyone ever seen anything like this before?

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 14):

I had the very same issue: I had added a method called "isDatabase" (returning a BOOL) to the parent entity of my Database entity, which had a relationship named "database". Renaming "isDatabase" to "isOfTypeDatabase" fixed the issue. So keep also looking in parent entities!

Comment: You just saved me potentially **hours** of frustration and Googling. If I could up vote this answer a thousand times I would. Thank you, sir!

Comment: OMG! Had the same issue, can't use "is<relationshipName>" even in a category! Renamed my method to something else fixed it! Thanks a lot :D!

Answer (score 2):

I defined a property on an `NSManagedObject` subclass that collided with the name of a relationship defined on the class.

Here's the code in my `MyManagedObjectSubclass+Custom.h`

`@property (readonly, nonatomic) BOOL isSeason;`

Here's the code produced by XCode for MyManagedObjectSubclass.h

`@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeOtherEntityToOneRelationship *season;`

Note that `isSeason`, by KVC, will collide with the season name

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem and after pulling my hair out for an entire day, I solved my problem.

I believe the problem is related to a corrupt attribute / relationship, and the NSCFNumber is actually looking for the objectID for that attribute / relationship. In my case, I could use valueForKey: to find all of the attributes / relationships, although a relationship I had called "file" seemed to be corrupt.

I finally realized that I had extended NSObject to include a boolean "isFile" method, and somehow this was interfering with CoreData and causing it to either return a corrupt object, or not be able to deal properly with the object it had. My guess is that CoreData must dynamically create "isXXX" methods.

I could either fix the problem by removing the isFile method, or by renaming my property.

Answer (score 0):

The objectID and entity selectors are on `NSManagedObject`, not `NSCFNumber` (or `NSNumber`). I wouldn't expect you to call either of these selectors on a `NSNumber` which should be a property on an entity, not the entity itself.

Every entity in CoreData must extend `NSManagedObject`, so your `NSCFNumber` object is not an entity.